# How to create a large demo table in quick time in MySQL And checking execution time, execution path

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand what is the easiest way to create a demo table with large data(say 10million) for performance testing purpose in mysql? Just to clarify a bit, say for example in Oracle or postgress we use something as below to create large data volume in quick time. But as I understand mysql doesn't have such thing exists but it can be done using stored procedure. So can you guide me with some sample one?

Additionally for checking execution time and execution path in Oracle and prostgres, we use 'set autotrace traceonly explain statistics' and 'explain analyze'. These commands execute the query behind the scene and give the elapsed time and execution path which the sql took, as output. What will be the similar statement in mysql for this?

Say for example, in Oracle using "connect by level" as below..

```sql
create table t as
select 
guid() as id, 
'Just some text' as textcol,
mod(rownum,5) as numcol1, 
mod(rownum,1000) as numcol2 , 
5000 as numcol3, 
to_date ('01.' || lpad(to_char(mod(rownum,12)+1),2,'0') || '.2018' ,'dd.mm.yyyy') as time_id 
from dual connect by level<=10000000 -- 10Million rows ; 

set autotrace traceonly explain statistics;
select * from t;
```

Say for example, in Postgres using "generate_series" as below..

```sql
insert into t (
    code, article, name, department
)
select
    gen_random_uuid() ,
    md5(random()::text),
    md5(random()::text),
    left(md5(random()::text), 4)
from generate_series(1, 10000000);

explain analyze select * from t;
```

Comment: MySQL have no generators implemented. You may use either recursive CTE (this is similar to Oracle's solution) or multile joined copies of some huge system table (for example, `mysql.help_relation` which contains ~2000 rows).

Comment: See MariaDB's sequence pseudo-table:  `seq_1_to_10000000` will generate a single column "table" with 10M rows.  You can use the value in that to generate dates or random number or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple stored procedure is one way.

Consider the following data

```
create table t (
  code text,
  article text,
  name text,
  department text );
```

Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addRows()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE i <= 10000000 DO
         insert into t (code,article,name,department ) 
         values(MD5(RAND()),MD5(RAND()),MD5(RAND()),LEFT(MD5(RAND()),4));
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Execute using the following statement

```
call addRows();
```

Execution plan

```
explain analyze select * from t;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/H7LcnBur)

Comment: Thank you @Ergest Basha. That helps. One doubt I have, Is the time which I am seeing seeing as output of 'explain analyze' like "actual time=0.075..45.666" is the actual time of the execution of the query or just the planning time? because if I am inserting rows of table T into another table T1 with 'explain analyze' statement appended, i see zero rows as the output of count(*), is the 'actual time'  its just the planning time but not the actual run time of the query? 
explain analyze INSERT INTO T1 select id from T;
select count(*) from T1;  --Its giving zero rows as output.

Comment: @sud check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze/#:~:text=What%20is%20it%3F,points%20in%20the%20execution%20plan.)

Comment: Got it. So it means , its the actual time the insert took from first row till the last row fully inserted. And that means the rows are just not committed which is why the count(*) is giving zero rows post explain analyze. Thank you so much @Ergest Basha for the details.